# How to ignore merge commit and squash rest of simple commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have no idea if this operation is possible or not but please let me know.

Assume this is my branch tree:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G 
           \              \
            \              f' -- f''
             c' -- c''
```

I want to squash this tree and change it into this one:

```
(AB) -- C -- (DE) -- F -- G 
           \          \
            \          f' -- f''
             c' -- c''
```

Comment: In this case it's more than one branch that will need to be rebased, and they would have to be done separately (already provided an answer for that).

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done in a single shot... but it's possible over some steps.

```
git rebase -i C G
# when the list of commits shows up, set D to pick, E to squash
# save and exit
# rebase will stop so you can setup a good commit comment for DE
# when you are done, save exit so the new DE commit is created
# and rebase will continue running so you get a new G history with DE
# now, let's rewrite f''
git rebase f''~2 f'' --onto new-F
```

And that should work to get the new desired history

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume these branch names:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G (g-branch)
           \              \
            \              f' -- f'' (f-branch)
             c' -- c'' (c-branch)
```

There are three “tips” that need to be updated. git-rebase(1) can
update more than one branch, but things need to be connected.

That’s not a problem. Just temporarily merge `c-branch` and `f-branch`
into `g-branch`.[1] [2]

```
git merge --no-edit --strategy ours --no-rerere-autoupdate f-branch c-branch
```

Use whatever conflict-don’t-care strategy (`ours` here) since we just
want the merge itself and don’t care about the result (it’s a throwaway
merge).

Then:

```
git rebase --interactive --update-refs --rebase-merges <commit before A>
```

Which will give you more or less this todo editor:

```
label onto

# Branch f-branch
reset onto
pick 7b4724b a
pick 0df1a0c b
pick c11a59d c
label branch-point-2
pick 98bb1ed d
pick 4d089d8 e
pick 4bd455c f
label branch-point
pick ae995c6 f'
pick f4cbaf2 f''
update-ref refs/heads/f-branch

label f-branch

# Branch f-branch-2
reset branch-point-2 # c
pick 1e668b0 c'
pick 579702e c''
update-ref refs/heads/c-branch

label f-branch-2

reset branch-point # f
pick b6eef93 g
merge -C b2bb5c4 f-branch f-branch-2 # Merge branches 'f-branch' and 'c-branch' into g-branch
```

Now we mark `squash` on commits “b” and “e” and delete the last `merge`
line.

Next we modify the two squash commit messages.

The output of this command:

```
$ git rebase --interactive --update-refs --rebase-merges 2de26a440ad4a23486b60f0228b0a0f70bed6cc0
[detached HEAD 0ed1c26] a b
 Date: Tue Apr 18 18:06:53 2023 +0200
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
[detached HEAD 3f6617c] d e
 Date: Tue Apr 18 18:08:23 2023 +0200
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/g-branch.
Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
    refs/heads/c-branch
    refs/heads/f-branch
```

Notice that the command says that the two other branches were updated as
well.

We needed:

- `--rebase-merges` in order to rebase a non-linear history which
  contained a merge (the one we just threw away)
- `--update-refs` in order to update all three branches, not just the
  one we started the rebase from (`g-branch`)

#### Confirmation

Now the first squash commit (AB) should be in all three branches:

```
$ # “a b” is the commit message
$ git branch --contains=:'/a b'
  c-branch
  f-branch
* g-branch
```

And the second squash commit (DE) should be in `f-branch` and
`g-branch`:

```
$ git branch --contains=:'/d e'
  f-branch
* g-branch
```

#### Notes

1. Using Git 2.40.0 for all commands
2. `--no-rerere-autoupdate` might not be needed

Answer (score 1):

Every commit is a full snapshot, so it's pretty much trivially easy to make new commits whose ancestors have the content and history you want.

```
    (AB) -- C -- (DE) -- F -- G 
               \          \
                \          f' -- f''
                 c' -- c''
```

Assuming A is a root commit,

```
git replace --graft B          # make B a root
git replace --graft E C        # E's parent is C
git filter-branch              # bake in the rewired ancestry
```

This will change the id's of all commits with new ancestry, here that's everything that remains.